# docusign REST API for sending Notification / Reminder to in-process envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Can anyone help me to send Notification/Reminder to the in-process envelope using docusign REST API ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Gangadhar, I'm planning to write a blog post on this topic in the next 2 weeks.
Until then here is a support article - https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000069k9e2SAA/rest-api-for-sending-notification-reminder-to-inprocess-envelope

The API is documented here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/updateNotificationSettings

And it's a `PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/notification`